# How to make a vertical endless scrolling background in SpriteKit Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I need to make a background for my game that infinitely scrolls from top to bottom. This is what I have right now but the background goes to the bottom but never goes back to the top. This is what I have right now. I am writing in swift 4 on xcode 9.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
   var ground = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        createGrounds()
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        moveGrounds()
    }

    func createGrounds() { 
        for i in 0 ... 3 {
            let ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backGround")
            ground.name = "Ground"
            ground.size = CGSize(width: (self.scene?.size.width)!, height: ((self.scene?.size.height)! * 2))
            ground.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y:0.5)
            ground.position = CGPoint(x: (CGFloat(i) * ground.size.height), y: (self.frame.size.height / 2))
            self.addChild(ground)
            print(i)
        }
    }

    func moveGrounds() {
        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Ground", using: ({
            (node, error) in

            node.position.y -= 7
            if node.position.y > ((self.scene?.size.height))! {
                node.position.y += (self.scene?.size.height)! / 3
            }
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when your code runs? i.e. What is it doing that you don't want it to do and what's it not doing that you do want it to do?

Comment: Steve Ives. My code runs fine but the screen I have runs all the way down but never repeats. it only does it once.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning the background is located at height `(self.frame.size.height / 2)`, on each move you decrement `y` by 7, thus `y` is always lesser than `(self.frame.size.height / 2)`, how do you think the condition `node.position.y > ((self.scene?.size.height))` could be true?

You should reset `y` when less than 0 or something like that (depending on the way you manage `anchor` and `position`).

Comment: I tried resetting it to 0 but now it goes all the way through but it resets to the top and makes it jump